# Dynamic sidebar width depending on the main div

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
 #main{
     width: 840px;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }

 #sidebar{
     float: left;
     width: ?; -> need to fill dhe auto space
 }
```

the problem is how i can make #sidebar div to fill the space left from the main div?
This image shows what i want

[image]

Comment: Center div must have always same width?

Comment: yes only the sidebar must be dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
 #sidebar{
     float: left;
     width: calc(100% - 840px);
 }
```

Comment: im noob to css is calc a css function?

Comment: yes it's a new css3 thing. There are webkit and mozzila specific versions too

Comment: @AntonioPapa Sadly, YES :P

Comment: But it's not work. Look main div must be in center on the page so left sidebar is 100% 0 840px / 2:)

Comment: @AntonioPapa So you don't need to divide for 2?

Comment: yes i divided by 2 but i choose this answer for copyright reasons :P

Answer (score 2):

Correct version based od **Jean-Bernard Pellerin** answer

```
#sidebar{
     float: left;
     width: calc((100% - 840px) / 2);
 }
```